# Pylons: question about websetup.py use

Tags: python, pylons, paster

reading pylons documentations I did understand that websetup:setup_app is only called when the application is setup at first time by paster script. But, I found now, setup_app is call every time that application starts. Debugging the code, this behaviour seems right because in appinstall.setup_config the module is loaded (as PRJ.websetup) and as it have the setup_app attribute, the function is called.

Can you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I was wrong. The websetup is used by the setup script and before the test are executed.

A controller make an import for a test module, and then setup_app is called.

Thanks!.